# monitor remote command locally

Tags: ssh

so I have a 3d printer hooked up to a laptop with Ubuntu. When I start up the service for the octo print, I like having the output in a terminal so I can monitor it when I'm downstairs. But, I need to be able to reboot and start the service remotely. Is there any way I can start it remotely, but then later monitor the output of the console if the remote(putty) is closed?

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/07/17/ubuntu-19-10-eoan-ermine-end-of-life-reached-on-july-17-2020/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: Edited the question to remove the reference to Ubuntu 19.10. The actual question ("*How can I accomplish X?*") does not seem related to a specific release of Ubuntu. However, the OP really needs to migrate to a supported release of Ubuntu -- 19.10 hasn't received security patches in 14 months, and certainly should not be on any networks!

Answer (score 2):

Use a Terminal Multiplexer like `screen` or `tmux`.

These simple-but-powerful applications keep a virtual terminal window open and running your application, even when you are not logged in.

You can run multiple virtual terminal windows. You can connect each one separately. You can connect using ssh for remote access.

Both `screen` and `tmux` are in the Ubuntu repositories, and both have many great tutorials across the net.